# Newbie trouble with sxml and php

Tags: php, xml

I have been trying to read a "node" from YouTube respons.
If ever delt with YouTube feeds you will know what I am talking about.
This is as simple a feed respons as I could get.

```
   <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
   <entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:media='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/'>
     <media:thumbnail url='http://i2.ytimg.com/i/8888888888888/1.jpg?v=888888'/>
   </entry>
```

The "88888888"'s are replaced info :-)

What I would like is a simple as possible way to have the URL for working with in PHP.

I have read other peoples examples and info on xml and PHP, but for some reason cant grab the URL.

Hope someone can help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK all..... I fixed it :)

Seems I was getting a conflict with another script.
So here is the working script for anyone that might need or want it.

```
     <?php
 $feed3 = 'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/'.$youtube.'?fields=media:thumbnail';

  // read feed into SimpleXML object
 $entry3 = simplexml_load_file($feed3);

  // get nodes in media: namespace for media information
 $media = $entry3->children('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');

 $attrs = $media->thumbnail[0]->attributes();
 $channel_thumbnail = $attrs['url']; 

 $profile_pic = '<div>
      <img src="' .  $channel_thumbnail  . '" width="50" height="50">
 </div>';
     ?>
```